# Add to existing value using .each() JQuery

Tags: jquery, function, loops, each

I have an `.each()` function that measures the width of each of the images within the class of `.item`. I need all the widths to be measured and then added to a variable. The variable then needs to be passed out of the function. This function below is only half done, I just dont know how to finish it off.

Any help much appreciated.

```
$('.item img').each(function () {

    var i = $(this).width();

});

$('.overview').css('width', i);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var i = 0;

$('.item img').each(function () {

    i = i + $(this).width();

});

$('.overview').css('width', i);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var i = 0;

$('.item img').each(function () {
    i += $(this).width();
});

$('.overview').css('width', i);
```

Answer (score 3):

You were iterating through the items but the width is over written instead of adding up.

```
var i = $(this).width();
```

this would be

```
var i += $(this).width();
```

Also define I outside function to retain its value between function calls. The variable name i is not very appropriate here it could be something like totalImagesWidth

Try this

```
var i = 0;
$('.item img').each(function () {

    i += $(this).width();

});


$('.overview').css('width', i);

// you can pass this to some other function as well
somefunction(i);
```

Comment: Good answer based on the question, the original asker might want to consider changing the name of the `i` var to something more descriptive.

Comment: Yes very true, i for variable name is not suited here. I mentioned in my answer to change i to more appropriate name.